# Proving that $W=W_1 \oplus W_2$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Given $W=M_{n \times n}(F)$ a vector space of square matrices with $F$ as a field such that $char(F)\neq2$.

Also, $W_1=\{A \in W: A^T=A\}$ and $W_2=\{A \in W: A_{ij}=0\:if\: i\leq j\}$

The objective is to prove that $W=W_1\oplus W_2$.

Clearly, $W_1\cap W_2=\{0\}$. ($0$ is the zero-matrix here)

So the problem now is to prove that, for every matrix $X \in M_{n\times n}(F)$, $X$ can be written as a sum of a symmetric matrix and a matrix who's upper triangle is zero.

Working with an example does the trick:

$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1&2&3 \\
    4&5&6 \\
    7&8&9
\end{bmatrix}
$=
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1&2&3 \\
    2&5&6 \\
    3&6&9
\end{bmatrix}
$+
$
\begin{bmatrix}
    0&0&0 \\
    2&0&0 \\
    4&2&0
\end{bmatrix}
$

Now, what about in general ?

I started off taking a general matrix $X$ in $W$ and wrote it as follows:

$X=aA+bB$ where a,b are constants and $A \in W_1$ and $B \in W_2$.

Taking transpose of both sides: $X^{T}=aA+bB^{T}$

Subtracting the above equation yields: $X-X^{T}=b(B-B^{T})$

Now, one thing I concluded from matrices from $W_2$ is that, if $B \in W_2$ then $B+B^{T}=Y$ where $Y^{T}=Y$ i.e. it yields a symmetric matrix.

So, $X-X^{T}=b(2B-Y)$.

The problem is, I am not able to conclude anything from here. The objective was to find such matrices $A$ and $B$, but it becomes confusing.

Does anything from above make sense ? Kindly help !

Answer (score 2):

You are complicating a relatively simple problem. Let $A\in W$ and define
$$(A_1)_{ij}:=\cases{A_{ij} & if $i\le j$,\\A_{ji} & if $i>j$.}$$
Then $A_1\in W_1$ and $A-A_1\in W_2$, giving you the desired decomposition.

Answer (score 1):

A dimensional argument can do the trick. Calculate the dimension of $W_1$ and $W_2$ and then use the dimension formula for subspaces
$$\dim(W_1 \oplus W_2)=\dim(W_1)+\dim(W_2)-\dim(W_1\cap W_2)$$
to show $\dim(M_{n\times n}(F))=\dim(W_1\oplus W_2)$.